# What is a simple way to validate if a double that contains 2 decimal places?

Tags: java

I'm looking for an example in Java to check if a double amount entered by a user contains 2 decimal places e.g. 99.99 entered would return valid and 99.9 or 99.999 entered would return invalid.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: SO is no code factory dude!

Comment: You can only do that as long as you have the input as `String` (and then it's trivial)

Comment: This question's crime is that it was not asked as a question with a "?". But the context is specific enough for useful and specific answers to be submitted. May be it's off-topic or not an appropriate question in this forum ?

Answer (score 5):

```
Double d = 234.12413;
String[] splitter = d.toString().split("\\.");
splitter[0].length();   // Before Decimal Count
int decimalLength = splitter[1].length();  // After Decimal Count

if (decimalLength == 2)
   // valid
else
   // invalid
```

> For Henry's question

```
double d1 = 0.50;
double d2 = d1%1;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

int decimalLength = (df.format(d2).length()-1);

if (decimalLength == 2)
   //valid
else
   // invalid
```

Note : `df.format(d2)` returns `.50` , so the **length** is `3`

Comment: Hmm, what about the entered number "0.50"?

Comment: You missed the point, when you have a double you can no longer distinguish the cases "1.5" (invalid) and "1.50" (valid).

Comment: Then, one should **check** the **string**. **If** the **Length** is 2 and **last digit** is **Zero**, then **return Valid**.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following regex

```
\d+(\.\d{2})?
```

Comment: what about number split with `,` instead `.` or rather internationalization of number format

Comment: `\d+\.\d{2}` to ensure that it has exactly 2 places after the decimal

Answer (score 1):

One more approach:

```
//assert that the string is valid number
String num = "99.99";  // I assume that is `String` because entered by user and not yet converted to `double`
int i = num.lastIndexOf('.');
if(i != -1 && num.substring(i + 1).length() == 2) {
    System.out.println("The number " + num + " has two digits after dot");
}
```

*ADDED
If you wand use local specific `decimal separator` use the result of following expession instead of `'.'`.

```
DecimalFormat format = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance();
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = format.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
//symbols.getDecimalSeparator() == '.';
```